# How to Automatically replace Lines of Code?

Tags: java, replace, io

I would imagine this question has been answered before however I am unable to find an answer for it so I figured I'd ask here.

If there is already a term for this, please inform me of it - thanks!

Anyways, currently I have bullets created as such:

```
bullet.create(x, y, xChange, yChange);
```

I would like to be able to enter

```
bullet.create(x, y, 40 <angle>, 5 <speed>);
```

or some such and then run it through a program to calculate `xChange` and `yChange` from the Angle and Speed (Which I already have) and have it edit the java file itself, as opposed to outputting into the console.

TL;DR:
How do I pull information from a java file, run it through an equation, and replace the input code with the equation's output?

Thanks!

Comment: I have to ask, why are you doing this? You have a class named bullet with speed and direction; it seems like you're doing some kind of animation or simulation. If you feel your best approach for changing the value of variables is to find/replace their values in the source files, you may wish to rethink your overall design.

Comment: Somebody had a good reply here with the obvious answer of just calculating angle and speed at runtime; e.g. `bullet.create(x, y, calcAngle(40), calcSpeed(5));` But for some reason they deleted it. I can't in good conscience post it as my own answer, but it's really the cleanest way to do it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use [reflection](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/reflect/) to pull information from a Java file. You could use a [`Scanner`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/api/java/util/Scanner.html) to read each line of the Java file, and then use a [`BufferedWriter`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/io/BufferedWriter.html) to write (overwrite) the Java file with the necessary changes.

Comment: If you're going to use reflection to set fields like that, you might as well just make some public setters and set the fields directly. Same end effect, saner path. :)

Comment: True, I was under the impression that he wanted to modify the Java file from within the program. Maybe I am just misinterpreting the question. Nonetheless, I will still throw in my 2 cents. :)